# Neo4j Behaviour of Merge

Tags: neo4j, cypher

So I have a use case where periodically I update my graph with complex subgraphs. In these subgraphs there will be nodes which are already in the graph, and nodes which are new. I had thought that Merge should do this, but in fact merge appears to create a new node even if there was already a unique node, if the property specifications are not identical.

E.g. on the [Neo4j Console](http://console.neo4j.org/), Suppose that I do:

```
MERGE (a:Crew {name:'Neo', occupation:'The One'})
MERGE (a:Crew {name:'Adam', occupation:'Mechanic'})
CREATE UNIQUE (a)-[r:KNOWS]->(b)
RETURN *
```

That causes the console to create a second version of Neo, rather than to simple attach the occupation to the existing version.

[image]

This happens even if you use:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (p:Crew) ASSERT p.name IS UNIQUE
```

Although now it just refuses to create anything since it won't match the two neo's as one property is blank, and it isn't allowed to create a new node either.

Answer (score 2):

It creates a second version because it's not unique.  You're specifying an additional property, "occupation", which doesn't currently exist in the original Neo node, so it doesn't find a match and therefore creates a new node.

Answer (score 2):

Use this instead:

```
MERGE (a:Crew {name:'Neo'}) ON CREATE SET a.occupation='The One'
MERGE (a:Crew {name:'Adam'}) ON CREATE SET b.occupation='Mechanic'
MERGE (a)-[r:KNOWS]->(b)
RETURN *
```

See also: http://docs.neo4j.org/refcard/2.1/

Comment: Yes, I appreciate this, but a given user is not guaranteed to know whether a field is filled out or not.

Comment: In our given use case, for example, there are several message standards from which we are harvesting information, and they share some fields but not others.